# Feature importance of learner used in benchmark experiment - mlr

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, mlr

I am using `mlr` package in R to compare two learners, i.e. random forest and lasso classifier, on a binary classification task. I used nested cross-validation to compute performance. Then, I would like to compute the features' importance for the best classifier, random forest in this case. To achieve this I am using `generateFeatureImportanceData()` which: "Estimate how important individual features or groups of features are by contrasting prediction performances. For method “permutation.importance” compute the change in performance from permuting the values of a feature (or a group of features) and compare that to the predictions made on the unmcuted data." As I specified `measure = auc`, does the output res provides the decrease in `auc` for each feature from permuting its value?

library(easypackages)

```
libraries("mlr","purrr","glmnet","parallelMap","parallel")

data = read.table("data_past.txt", h = T)

set.seed(123)

task = makeClassifTask(id = "past_history", data = data, target = 
"DIAG", positive = "BD")

#specifying hyperparameters for random forest
ps_rf = makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("mtry", lower = 4, upper = 
16),makeDiscreteParam("ntree", values = 1000))

ctrl_rf = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)

inner = makeResampleDesc("RepCV", fold = 10, reps = 3, stratify = TRUE)

lrn_rf = makeLearner("classif.randomForest", predict.type = "prob", 
fix.factors.prediction = TRUE)

lrn_rf = makeTuneWrapper(lrn_rf, resampling = inner, par.set = ps_rf, 
control = ctrl_rf, measures = auc, show.info = FALSE)

parallelStartMulticore(36)

ft_im = generateFeatureImportanceData(task = task, method = 
"permutation.importance", learner = lrn_rf, measure = auc) 

parallelStop()

t(ft_im$res)
                                auc
INC2_A                 0.000000e+00
INC2_B                 0.000000e+00
INC2_F                 0.000000e+00
INC2_G                 0.000000e+00
INC2_H                 0.000000e+00
INC2_I                 0.000000e+00
SEX                    0.000000e+00
marital               -3.211696e-07
inpatient              0.000000e+00
CMS_1                  0.000000e+00
CMS_2                  0.000000e+00
CMS_3                  0.000000e+00
CMS_4                  0.000000e+00
CMS_5                  0.000000e+00
CMS_6                  0.000000e+00
CMS_7                  0.000000e+00
CMS_8                  0.000000e+00
CMS_9                  0.000000e+00
CMS_10                 0.000000e+00
CMS_11                 0.000000e+00
CMS_12                 0.000000e+00
CMS_13                 0.000000e+00
CMS_14                 0.000000e+00
OCS_1                  0.000000e+00
OCS_2                  0.000000e+00
OCS_3                  0.000000e+00
OCS_4                  0.000000e+00
OCS_5                  0.000000e+00
OCS_6                  0.000000e+00
OCS_7                  0.000000e+00
OCS_8                  0.000000e+00
OCS_9                  0.000000e+00
OCS_10                 0.000000e+00
OCS_11                 0.000000e+00
reta                   0.000000e+00
MH_F1                 -1.051220e-03
CP_1BA                 0.000000e+00
CP_1BS                 0.000000e+00
MIXCLINICAL3           0.000000e+00
MIXCLINICAL2           0.000000e+00
MIXDS52Simpt           0.000000e+00
MIXDS53Simpt           0.000000e+00
PAN                    0.000000e+00
OBS                    0.000000e+00
PHO                    0.000000e+00
GAD                    0.000000e+00
EAT_0                  0.000000e+00
ADHD                   0.000000e+00
BORDERLINEPERSONALITY  0.000000e+00
AlcoolProbUse          0.000000e+00
SubstanceProbUse       0.000000e+00
BMI                   -2.954760e-06
DEP_AGE               -7.996641e-04
NBD_P                 -1.669455e-03
NBDEP                 -8.671578e-06
NBSUI                 -2.055485e-06
NBHOS                 -8.091225e-03
DURDEP                -1.380869e-04
SEV_M                 -3.083132e-03
SEV_D                  0.000000e+00
CMS_sum                0.000000e+00
TOTMIXDSM5             0.000000e+00
GAF                   -1.170663e-05
Age                   -1.172269e-06
Comorbidities_sum      0.000000e+00
```

Are the features with the highest absolute value the more important ones? Does zero value for `auc` mean that the feature is irrelevant for the classification task at hand? Thank you.

Comment: Since your question is only about a statistical interpretation of results and not about how to get something running / facing coding errors, please consider posting such questions on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ in the future :)

Comment: Some remarks to your code: the `benchmark()` call and all of the wrappers beforehand are not important for your questions, it is only about the `generateFeatureImportanceData()` call (which does not depend on the former). Also please consider formatting your code to a width ~ 80 in the future to avoid long horizontal scrolling for the readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The score of a feature is obtaining by subtracting the normal prediction score of your model to the prediction score obtained with the permuted feature.

Therefore, features with AUC drop = 0 are irrelevant in the sense that they do not bring any value added (they are as important as if they were purely random noise). On the other hand features with the highest absolute values are the most important, as changing them influences the score the most.

Comment: would you be able to address a couple more points? 1) Should the sum of the absolute values in the column 'auc' (i.e. the metric at hand) equate to the overall performance of the tested leaner? 2) How should one go about picking the right number iterations ('nmr' argument in the function)? I would be grateful if you could refer me to any good source. Thank you!